# Open CollectionEditor dialog from smart tag function

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-server-controls

I have the custom control, and create smart tag for the control. The control have the collection property, i used collection editor in design time for the collection proeprty i need same in the smart tag. Actually i need to open the default collection editor when i click the smart tag Action Item.

i have the control like this.

[image]

when i click EditColumn item i need to open the collectioneditor like below

[image]

Simply, how to open the collectioneditor when click smart tag items?. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the solution. I created the new class which implements IWindowFOrmEditorServeice and IServiceProvider interfaces for showing the collection editor form. I manually invoked the 
EditValue method of UITypeEditor class and pass the new class as designer which implements the IWindowFOrmEditorServeice and IServiceProvider interfaces.Using that i am able to invoke colectioneditor in smart tags. :)